# Using windows authentication to log on to site using c#

Tags: c#, windows-authentication

I want to log on to a server inside my program using Windows authentication of the current user logged in. I thought that perhaps I could use

System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

but while that does give a name, I do not see how I can find out the password of the user to enter it.

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely no way to get the Windows user's password since Windows doesn't even store it (all it stores is an irreversible hash).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the password. You need to use Impersonation to pass on the identity to the server that you are trying to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use their password to a basic login unless the user provides it to your application. You'll have to do some sort impersonation or delegate authority based on the locally logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

in web.config:

```
  <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <identity impersonate="true"/>
  </system>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the Windows User Authentication, you should probably use some part of it that is more secure than the simple username/password combination. (And there is probably no way to access the password, as that would mean that every .NET application could access your full account information.)

For instance, [WindowsIdentity.User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.user.aspx) is stated to be unique for a user across all Windows NT implementations. (I believe this means that in any Windows NT implementation, this will be unique for each user on a given system... But I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 0):

If both the client and the server are in the same domain, you don't have to specify the username and password.

If you are using HttpRequest, you should set the [LogonUserIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.logonuseridentity.aspx).

If you are calling a SOAP service, you should set the [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.webclientprotocol.credentials.aspx) property.